# Function not returning data in Rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am calling below function in rxjava to get top stories :

```
public Observable<Integer> getStories(final Story.FILTER FILTER) {
    return api.getStories(FILTER)
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<ContentValues>, Observable<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Integer> call(final List<ContentValues> stories) {
                    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                            Log.e("Total size",""+stories.size());
                            refreshPreferences.saveRefreshTick(FILTER);
                            dataPersister.persistStories(stories);
                            subscriber.onNext(stories.size());
                            subscriber.onCompleted();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

It is further calling below function for get all stories:

```
public Observable<List<ContentValues>> getStories(final Story.FILTER FILTER) {

    return hackerNewsService.getTopStories()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<Long>, Observable<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Long> call(final List<Long> dataSnapshot) {
            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super Long> subscriber) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataSnapshot.size(); i++) {
                        subscriber.onNext(dataSnapshot.get(i));
                    }
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            });
        }
    }).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Post>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Post> call(final Long storyRoot) {
                    return hackerNewsService.getStoryItem(String.valueOf(storyRoot));
                }
            }).flatMap(new Func1<Post, Observable<ContentValues>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<ContentValues> call(final Post story) {
            return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<ContentValues>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super ContentValues> subscriber) {
                    Log.e("StoryTitle",""+story.getTitle());
                    ContentValues contentValues = mapStory(story);

                    if (story != null) {
                        subscriber.onNext(contentValues);
                    } else {
                        subscriber.onNext(new ContentValues());
                        //Inject.crashAnalytics().logSomethingWentWrong("HNewsApi: onDataChange is empty in " + story.getTitle());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).toList();
}
```

I am using flatmap to transform the data from one form to other. Now when I run the code I don't get the data return to my first function where i am saving data in persistent store. Second function is returning correct data.

I don't know what mistake I am doing here. I am new to rxjava so i would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `Observable.create()` but use the more appropriate `map` and `flatMapIterable` operators instead. This way, the Observable protocol is honored throughout the flow:

```java
public Observable<Integer> getStories(final Story.FILTER FILTER) {
    return api.getStories(FILTER)
        .map(new Func1<List<ContentValues>, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(final List<ContentValues> stories) {
                 Log.e("Total size",""+stories.size());
                 refreshPreferences.saveRefreshTick(FILTER);
                 dataPersister.persistStories(stories);
                 return stories.size();
            }
        });
}

public Observable<List<ContentValues>> getStories(final Story.FILTER FILTER) {

    return hackerNewsService.getTopStories()
        .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Long>, List<Long>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Long> call(final List<Long> dataSnapshot) {
                return dataSnapshot;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<Post>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Post> call(final Long storyRoot) {
                return hackerNewsService.getStoryItem(String.valueOf(storyRoot));
            }
        })
        .map(new Func1<Post, ContentValues>() {
            @Override
            public ContentValues call(final Post story) {
                Log.e("StoryTitle",""+story.getTitle());
                ContentValues contentValues = mapStory(story);

                if (story != null) {
                    return contentValues;
                }
                return new ContentValues();
        })
        .toList();
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with my approach?

Comment: That `Observable.create()` requires you to implement the protocol yourself, but in this case, there exist operators that do the same thing you tried to implement yourself. Also you need a finite sequence for `toList` which you forgot to complete in a previous create.